# How can I remove empty place in char array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Testtest{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String einString = Terminal.askString("String: ");
        String[] arrayWord = einString.split("");
        char[] arrayChar = einString.toCharArray();
        char[] count = new char[arrayChar.length];
        int[] number = new int[count.length];

        for(int i=0; i<arrayWord.length; i++){

            if((byte)arrayChar[i]>64&&(byte)arrayChar[i]<91){
                count[i] = arrayChar[i];
                if((byte)arrayChar[i]>96&&(byte)arrayChar[i]<123){
                    for(int j=i+1; j<count.length-1; j++){
                        count[j] = count[j+1];
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(count.length);
    }
}
```

[image]

As a result, I want to get only the number of Uppercase Alphabet when the user input the string. But as you see in the image, I succefully remove the lowercase of Alphabet, but the problem is it remains as a empty place. so when I use .length, these are counted. what should I have to do?

Comment: Array is a rigid data type, what you need is a dynamic array like list where you could remove the elements. IF you want to stick with array then you would need to shift your elements while separately maintain a count which would give length of valid characters in an array.

Comment: Why don't you just print out the letter if your `if` clause is true, and don't print if it's false?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand everything in your code (for instance, what's the use of the inner loop?).
If you want to keep only uppercase characters in a string, here is a possibility with streams. Given a string `s`, you have two relevant streams: `s.chars()` and `s.codePoints()`:

```
public class StringTest {
    private static String filterUpperCase1(String s) {
        return s.chars().filter(Character::isUpperCase)
                             .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                             .toString();
    }

    private static String filterUpperCase2(String s) {
        int[] a = s.chars().filter(Character::isUpperCase).toArray();
        return new String(a, 0, a.length);
    }

    private static String filterUpperCase3(String s) {
        return s.codePoints().filter(Character::isUpperCase)
                             .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                             .toString();
    }

    private static String filterUpperCase4(String s) {
        int[] a = s.codePoints().filter(Character::isUpperCase).toArray();
        return new String(a, 0, a.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "AaBbCc";
        System.out.println(filterUpperCase1(s));
        System.out.println(filterUpperCase2(s));
        System.out.println(filterUpperCase3(s));
        System.out.println(filterUpperCase4(s));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

Here `filterUpperCase1` and `filterUpperCase2` illustrate the kind of problem than can happen with `char`, instead of codepoints. By using `String.toCharArray()` in your code you will have the same problem.

Note that the first six characters are ASCII letters, while the latter six characters are [mathematical characters](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf) outside of the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

A `char` is a 16-bit value that may or may not equate a character (it does only for characters in the BMP), while a codepoint can encode any Unicode character. Here I don't consider [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) and [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Here there is an additional bug in `filterUpperCase1` and `filterUpperCase2` due to the fact that `Character.isUpperCase(int)` expects a codepoint, but transtyping to `char` in order to call `Character.isUpperCase(char)` would not change the output.